# cut length of string Selenium ide

Tags: string, selenium, string-length

What is the Code necessary to cut the length of a string?
Lets say I have the `${var}="abcdefghijklmn"` and `${var2}="cdefghijklmnopqr"` but I want both of them to stop after 6 letters. So `${var}` would be `"abcdefgh"` and `${var2}` would be `"cdefghij"`.

Comment: Why do you want the IDE to do that?

Comment: I got a couple of test I'm running via a GO-Pipline and I need to compare two strings but one of them is always longer than the other and I need them both to have the same length in order to compare them

Comment: Does no one know how to do this? @marksweb

Answer (score -1):

This is a copy and paste from "How to split the string 1 out of 20, into "1" and "20"

```
|store | 1 out of 20 | Text |

|storeEval | "${Text}".split(" ")[0] | firstsection |

|echo | ${firstsection} | |

[info] echo: 1

|storeEval | "${Text}".split(" ")[3] | lastsection |

|echo | ${lastsection} | |

[info] echo: 20
```